# No data saved with AJAX POST request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems with a jQuery form submission. Here is my jQuery code;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'chat/password.php',
    data: $("#roomform").serialize(),
    success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

However, it will only ever alert the following text;

```
Data saved:
```

With no data.

The PHP that returns data is;

```
if(!$roompass) {
    echo "0";
}else{
    if(!$check) {
        echo "0";
    }else{
        if($roompass == $check['password']) {
            echo "1";
        }else{
            echo "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, what does `password.php` output? Maybe it sends no data?

Comment: What should it output? Are there any specifics?

Comment: You should know what you expect it to return, shouldn't you?

Comment: Felix, I mean should it return the data, should it return something to say whether it worked or not... etc.

Comment: What `password.php` sends back to you? Any message like `echo "Transaction was successful.";` is there?

Comment: Is either prints a 1 or a 0, depending on what data was given. Should it be something else?

Comment: It does not matter what it returns. You seem to *expect* it to return something. So the question is, what do you expect? If it is not returning anything then of course `msg` will be empty. I'm confused about your confusion. Please post the relevant part of your PHP script.

Comment: @Thomas: Is it? Or *should* it? Inspect the HTTP response with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Thomas It might be best if you post the PHP source for chat/password.php, too, so we can see exactly what you expect to receive back in "data" when you call it, what Content-Type you're sending, etc.

Comment: Better post relevant part of your php code.

Comment: Done. I've posted the part that would return data.

Comment: It seems to be an error with my PHP - I've just added another else statement in the PHP and it returned fine. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What was that error? And what you have added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to active ajax only when you submit the form and prevent the default browser form submission.

```
$('#roomform').sumbit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       async: true,
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'chat/password.php',
       data: $("#roomform").serialize(),
       success: function(msg) {
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I already am, it's in a large piece of jQuery. This is already done.